# Can we integrate firebase analytics in old project which has google cloud messaging? so i want firebase-analytics and google cloud messaging also

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I have tried to add fire base-analytics in old project which has google cloud messaging which i don't want to change, i am getting error for google cloud message for imports.

Comment: Not possible to help without code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) as of 10 April 2018.

You can import the old project into Firebase Console and generate a config file. Analytics is a core service and track most of the app data automatically with few lines of code required for initialization. Take a look at this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start).

Please note that the Analytics data will start populating on Firebase dashboard only from the point onwards you integrate the SDK in the app. Also you can easily transition to Firebase Cloud Messaging with that approach.